# Ray refraction and how to keep track of the environment type?

Tags: game-physics, raytracing

Ray refraction and how to keep track of the environment type?

Should my Ray object know about the environment it is in? For example is it
air, glass, or else? By knowing the environment, i mean knowing the refraction index.
That way, when it hits a surface I can get the hit surface refraction index, and I can
compute the refracted ray.

Any suggestions how to manage this whole thing, the ray moving through different environments?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is really about code design finding the simplest answer for your needs. You might find this answer useful,

[How to deal with refraction when the rays start inside of a nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858662/how-to-deal-with-refraction-when-the-rays-start-inside-of-a-nested-object/4584391#4584391)

It solves the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The surface should hold the refraction index, so when you detect the collision between the ray and surface , you grab the index from the surface object and do calculations to deviate the ray based on the calculated result. If the index is global for a set of objects in a enviroment, the surface object could have an static reference to the enviroment which contains the refraction index, something like this:

```
class Surface {
private:  
    Enviroment* pEnviroment;
    ...
}; 

Ray Ray::refract(const Surface& surface) { 
   double index = surface.getEnviroment()->getRefractionIndex();
   ...
   // Do refraction calculation
}
```

Comment: But that way you assume the ray comes from air inside the surface?

Comment: So if the ray comes IN the surface I can use the refraction index as you said, but if the ray goes from the surface OUT of it, I guess I can use the reciprocal of the refraction index.

Comment: Or, you can use the normal of the surface to know if it impacted from "above" or "below" the surface as well

Comment: Yes, I can use refraction_index when the ray comes from ray inside the object, and use 1/refraction_index when the ray goes from the object to the outside in air. But this way you only consider going from air to object and vice versa. What if you go from one object into another? For example if you have two spheres intersecting

Comment: You don't need to invert the refraction index or keep track of the ray source, the refractive coefficient is a property of the surface, when the ray enters the surface (air, liquid, glass, etc), its the surface that bents the ray, if two spheres intercepts, the first surface (when the ray comes from air) bents the ray, and when it hits another sphere is bent again (with the intercepting sphere refraction index)

Comment: Check [this out](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Raytracing_Topics_Techniques-Part_3_Refractions_and_Beers_Law.shtml) for additional info