# Forward based ray tracer in C++

Tags: c++, graphics, simulation, raytracing

I am making a Ray Tracer in C++, and need it to be forward based (source to detector) instead of backwards based (detector to source). I need this as I am using it to model particular materials and their properties when interacting with light.

There are a lot of Ray Tracing tutorials available for backward direction, which is understandable as it makes more sense when writing ray tracing for graphics purposes, but I can not find any good ones for forward direction tracing (light source to detector.)

Does anyone know of any good forward based tutorials, or have a forward based ray tracer that they wouldn't mind me building on for non-profit purposes?

Comment: I'm afraid this is off-topic on SO, as it isn't a specific programming question. I'm not sure if there's a more appropriate sister site, but you can browse the full list by clicking 'more stack exchange communities' in the top-left menu.

Comment: There's probably a really good reason everyone does it backwards. I think it might be the shear quantity of rays to keep track of. A ray hitting a complex surface could produce thousands of reflected/refracted rays.

Comment: I'm not downvoting but I'm vote-closing because this is off-topic here. You might have better luck elsewhere

Comment: I think there are few tutorials because it's substantially harder and doesn't really fit the "instant gratification" formula of tutorials. You might have better luck searching for "radiosity", though.

Comment: As mentioned by others, pure forward ray tracing is horribly inefficient, as almost no ray ever hits the detector. Check out [Photon Mapping](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall02/cs526/papers/course43sig02.pdf) for a nice way of combining both forward and backward ray-tracing steps in an efficient way.

Comment: Please confirm that you are interested in refraction as well as reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Its a matter of optimization to the point where the raytracer is capable of tracing a scene before the sun becomes a red giant. Blindly doing forward raytracing with a scene of some complexity requires many many rays to be traced, until an image is generated. Basically you have no guarantee that a selected "source" ray will end up at the image before-hand, so you'l have to keep trying new rays until you're lucky to have filled the image.

I don't quite follow why the forward direction is a requirement. When a ray has been traced from a pixel in the image to a source, you could simply traverse that ray in the forward direction as needed.

Comment: I'm not generating an image, I'm simulating photon interactions within a material. The ray tracing I'm doing isn't for a graphical purpose. It's for material design purpose. My material has some funny optical purposes, which make no sense in reverse. It needs to be forward because I'm modelling specific interactions within the material, that have to be in the forward direction. I'm not really worried about there not being that many photons modelled.

Comment: Well in that case, I think the problem boils down to how to select rays (from the source) which will hit the surface of interest. Perhaps you can use just directional sources (Sort of like the sun, being quite far away, so sun-rays are approximately parallel across a surface).

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to this question, [How to deal with refraction when the rays start inside of a nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858662/how-to-deal-with-refraction-when-the-rays-start-inside-of-a-nested-object/4584391#4584391). In it I describe the steps needed to simulate the propagation of photons in dielectric materials. I discuss how to,

- design a nice API for (if you are using an object oriented approach) for ray-tracing,
- deal with the tricky boundary problem between an interface connecting two dielectics,
- and apply reflection and reflection and interfaces.

There is also an companying Python project.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a raytracer once and there's a simple reason for the forward ray tracer not being (or mostly certainly not being) possible to write. If the scene is complicated, you have no way of knowing, where to shoot the rays to hit every single pixel on your detector.

What you may do is to do backward ray-tracing and then, when you already know the path ray will be following, do the forward tracing to compute some additional data.

Comment: I don't need to fill an image. I'm not creating an image. All I need is to simulate how many photons hit my detector, and any that hit a barrier outside my material can be killed.

Comment: Yeah, but my point is, that you have no way of knowing even if the shoot photon will end up *somewhere near* the barrier. It may as well hit other side of the scene after bouncing on some objects. On the other hand, if you have some specific requirements, it seems, that you define rules here and - thus - you won't find much documents on the Internet about it.

Comment: It doesn't matter. If the photon ends up somewhere near the barrier, it hasn't hit my detector. If for example, I have a solar panel as my detector, then if the photon doesn't hit my solar panel, then I can't use the energy from the photon. Forward raytracing is possible to write, it's been done. The GEANT4 toolkit has a forward ray tracer, but I was hoping for some form of tutorial or toolkit before I had to start digging into the depths of GEANT4 as it's quite a complex programme.